# Can I open an URL(a Facebook page) in a FBDialog or something in FBConnect?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, fbconnect

I am struggling to find this. Can I open a URL in a FBDialog or using something in FBConnect. I tried to do it like the following. But it doesn't seem to be working.

```
FBDialog *dlg = [FBDialog new];
[dlg loadURL:@"http://www.facebook.com/pages/Apple-Inc/137947732957611" get:nil];
```

I don't even know whether this is possible or not. Can you guys please help me?

Comment: I assume you just want to reuse the dialog view right?

Comment: Mmm I don't know whether reusing is the right term or not, but I just want to open an URL just as opening one in a UIWebView.

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 problem to prevent you from your code. First, when you pass a url to -loadURL:get: method, Facebook iOS SDK rebuild the real url base on yours. So, the url you passed will not get into the webview finally. What you need to do is implementing a method in FBDialog.m like this:

```
-(void)hackLoadURL:(NSString*)url withDelegate:(id)delegate {
    _webView.delegate = delegate;
    [_webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]];
}
```

The second problem is that you need to hack the

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;
```

delegate method and replaced with the one you make implementation. But in order to keep the original Facebook SDK works, you need to add below code to FBDialog.m

```
_webView.delegate = self;
```

within -loadURL:get: method, and before this line

```
[_webView loadRequest:request];
```

finally, you need to implement

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;
```

yourselves in your class, and use

```
FBDialog *dlg = [FBDialog new];
[dlg hackLoadURL: yourExpectUrl withDelegate: self];
```

to do what you wanted.